# Change the style class of element conditionally in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, triggers, styles

I'm trying to change the class of a Frame depending on a variable value.
I tried changing the "class", "ClassId" and "StyleClass" properties.
I also tried with triggers, but finally I had to change it this way.
Is there any way to do it more elegant? What if I need to change more styles conditionally?

I tried this:

```
<Frame x:Name="FilaListaEventos" class="{Binding Alerts}">
```

And this:

```
<Frame x:Name="FilaListaEventos" StyleClass="{Binding Alerts}">
```

And this:

```
<Frame x:Name="FilaListaEventos" ClassId="{Binding Alerts}">
```

And also tried this:

```
<Frame StyleClass="ListRow">
   <Frame.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding Alerts}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="ClassId" Value="ListRowAlerts" />
      </DataTrigger>
   </Frame.Triggers>
   ...
```

But finally I got it this way:

```
<Frame StyleClass="ListRow">
   <Frame.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding Alerts}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
      </DataTrigger>
   </Frame.Triggers>
   ...
```

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve, What do you mean by changing the style class? Can you explain? or simply tell us what are you trying to do so maybe we could guide you to the correct path?

Comment: I'm trying to change the ViewCell style of a ListView depending on the value of a property in my model.

Comment: If I am not wrong you can use VisualStateManager https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager&ved=2ahUKEwiM2ZWdg5zoAhWo7XMBHerkAiYQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw054VgNGFHYOlQzOVkreN0k

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that you had to wait two years, but this is how I did it.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static Your Property}}" Value="Required Value">
         <Setter Property="YourProperty" Value="YourValue"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```